# Customizing Apache Camels ExchangeFormatter using Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

by default i assume that spring-boot/camel is using   `org.apache.camel.support.processor.DefaultExchangeFormatter`.
I wonder how I can set the flag 'showHeaders' inside a spring-boot app.
Because I hope to see the headers in the "org.apache.camel.tracing" log as well.
Wish all a wonderful day

Answer (score 1):

DefaultTracer is used in Camel to trace routes by default.
It is created with `showHeaders(false)` formatter option set.
Therefore you could implement another Tracer (consider extending from DefaultTracer) to enable putting headers into traced messages.

Answer (score 0):

i need this mostly in my tests. so i have built this into my basic test class

```
@BeforeEach
public void before() {
     if( camelContext.getTracer().getExchangeFormatter() instanceof DefaultExchangeFormatter ) {
         DefaultExchangeFormatter def = (DefaultExchangeFormatter)camelContext.getTracer().getExchangeFormatter();
         def.setShowHeaders(true);
     }          
}
```